# dynamically update breadcrumb & highlight active color

Tags: javascript

I am sorry for the title. I don't no how to write the title for the below scenario .

The below question would be easier for an expert. Kindly bear with my English.

I am creating a single page portfolio. In the web site I have top menu,breadcrumb,content & footer.

If i click any menu or submenu the corresponding div is loading properly but I want to change my breadcrumb dynamically based on the menu

Here is the HTML code for top menu

```
 <div id="eyMenuNav">
  <ul id="navmenu">
    <li class="on">
      <a class='link1' href="#first">Article on Technology</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="sub" href="#">Success Stories</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class='link2' href="#second" onclick="onctext();">Customer Quotes</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class='link3' href="#third" onclick="onctext();">CSS, Appreciation - Metrics</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class='link4' href="#four" onclick="onctext();">Lesson Learnt</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class='link5' href="#five">Hexaware Key Contributor</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the HTML code for breadcrumb

```
<div id="eyBreadCrumb">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="crumb" href="#"><!-- Here I need update my breadcrumb based on the link which i clicked -></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Clearing Element -->
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <!-- end breadcrumb --> </div>
```

Here Is the code for javascript which i tried it is working for one menu click but i want for all.

```
function onctext()
{
document.getElementById("crumb").innerHTML="Success Stories - Customer Quotes";
}
```

Kindly help me for the above scenario

Note : I am not using jquery only iam working with javascript.

Thanks
Mahadevan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `this` parameter to your `onctext()` call, so your menu items look like so:

```
<a class='link3' href="#third" onclick="onctext(this);">CSS, Appreciation - Metrics</a>
```

And then change your `onctext` function to retrieve the text from `this`:

```
function onctext(elm) {
    var text = elm.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("crumb").innerHTML = text;

    // set active class
    var active = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];
    if (active) {
        active.className = active.className.replace(' active', '');
    }
    elm.className += ' active';
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion now can you please help me how to change my active class to the corresponding link which i clicked